# Angular 8 mat-autocomplete ERROR - 'matAutocomplete' since it isn't a known property of 'input'

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

Im trying to use the example [here](https://material.angular.io/components/chips/examples) from materialUI
working with Angular 8
the mat-chip-list works fine without the mat-autocomplete but I need it.
and this is my code:

```
        <mat-chip-list #chipList aria-label="Content selection">
          <mat-chip *ngFor="let item of content" [selectable]="selectable"
                   [removable]="removable" (removed)="remove(item)">
            {{item}}
            <mat-icon matChipRemove *ngIf="removable">cancel</mat-icon>
          </mat-chip>
          <input matInput 
                 #contentInput
                 [formControl]="contentCtrl" 
                 [matAutocomplete]="auto"
                 [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
                 [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCodes]="separatorKeysCodes"
                 [matChipInputAddOnBlur]="addOnBlur"
                 (matChipInputTokenEnd)="add($event)">
        </mat-chip-list>
        <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" (optionSelected)="selected($event)">
          <mat-option *ngFor="let item of filteredContent | async" [value]="item">
            {{item}}
          </mat-option>
        </mat-autocomplete>
      </mat-form-field>
```

and I get this error:

```
Can't bind to 'matAutocomplete' since it isn't a known property of 'input'. ("
        #contentInput
        [formControl]="contentCtrl" 
        [ERROR ->][matAutocomplete]="auto"
        [matChipInputFor]="chipList"
        [matChipInputSeparatorKeyCode"): ng:///AppModule/InviteMemberComponent.html@60:8
    at syntaxError (compiler.js:2175)
    at TemplateParser.parse (compiler.js:11388)
    at JitCompiler._parseTemplate (compiler.js:25963)
    at JitCompiler._compileTemplate (compiler.js:25951)
    at compiler.js:25895
    at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at JitCompiler._compileComponents (compiler.js:25895)
    at compiler.js:25808
    at Object.then (compiler.js:2166)
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (compiler.js:25807)
```

I don't understand why I'm getting this error :(

Comment: can you post your app.module.ts

Comment: @Sajeetharan I just fixed the issue, the solution has been added to this post.
Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Issue fix:

```
1) open app.module.ts 
2) import MatAutocompleteModule from @angular/material
3) add MatAutocompleteModule to the NgModule imports
```

fixed the issue for me!

Comment: It doesn't work for me.